# How to add hover class to jQuery click(function() accordian divs?

Tags: jquery, css

This is a very simple accordion that opens the `hh-content-entry` divs on click, each div independent from the other:

jQuery:

```
$(".hh-content-entry").slideUp();
$(".hh-title-entry").click(function(){
$(this).next(".hh-content-entry").slideToggle("slow");
```

html:

```
<div class="hh-title-entry">Week One</div>
<div class="hh-entry-content">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing.</div>

<div class="hh-title-entry">Week Two</div>
<div class="hh-entry-content">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing.</div>

<div class="hh-title-entry">Week Three</div>
<div class="hh-entry-content">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing.</div>
```

**Question:** how would I add an "hover" class to the `.hh-title-entry` titles? They are not traditional `a href` links, and the usual `a:hover` CSS doesn't apply.

I don't need an active class; I can do that in .hh-content-entry, because each div is hidden until open. But a hover class for the `.hh-title-entry` divs would be nice, both those that are open and closed.

Ideas?

**Fiddle at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xNt5/4/)**

Comment: Why not .hh-title-entry:hover ?

Comment: Argg...that was simple. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it. What's the CSS difference between .hh-title-entry:hover and .hh-title-entry a:hover?

Comment: .class:hover is the hover state of the class. .class a:hover is the hover state of an *a* that is a descendant of a element of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:hover` is perfectly fine to use on `.hh-title-entry` as well.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

From the link above:

> The :hover selector can be used on all elements, not only on links.